# Making a gradient background continue the last color

Tags: html, css

So I have a background:

[image]

I want this background to appear pretty much like it is and then repeat vertically, but instead of the rest of the background being white, I want it to be the same color as the last color on that gradient.

My CSS:

```
body {
background-image:url('background.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-size: 20%;
}
```

This makes it take up 20% of my background size and then leaving a trail of white which I want turned into the last color of the gradient.

Comment: You should be able to achieve this effect with CSS3, not using any images at all. Have you played around with any "css3 linear gradient generator" tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
background-color:#86a6b5;
```

To you CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2KYWL/

Comment: That sure did it! How did you come up with the exact color if I may ask?

Comment: Ther're many color-picker utilities, for example http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/ - it allows you to point to any part of the screen and grab color info

Comment: The chrome "Web Developer" extension also has a color picker

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `background-color`:

```
body {
  background-color:blue;
  background-image:url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-size: 20%;
}
```